# Spring Boot Jpa @ManyToOne : ForeignKey column in DB always populated to null

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, many-to-many

**Employee.Java**

`

```
import lombok.ToString;
    import javax.persistence.*;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;
    @ToString
    @Entity
    public class Employee {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        private int empid;
        private String empname;
        private String empcontact;
        private String empemail;
        private String empphoto;
        @OneToMany(mappedBy = "employee", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
        private List<Skillset> skillset;

 public int getEmpid() {
        return empid;
    }

    public void setEmpid(int empid) {
        this.empid = empid;
    }

    public String getEmpname() {
        return empname;
    }

    public void setEmpname(String empname) {
        this.empname = empname;
    }

    public String getEmpcontact() {
        return empcontact;
    }

    public void setEmpcontact(String empcontact) {
        this.empcontact = empcontact;
    }

    public String getEmpemail() {
        return empemail;
    }

    public void setEmpemail(String empemail) {
        this.empemail = empemail;
    }

    public String getEmpphoto() {
        return empphoto;
    }

    public void setEmpphoto(String empphoto) {
        this.empphoto = empphoto;
    }

    public List<Skillset> getSkillset() {
        return skillset;
    }

    public void setSkillset(List<Skillset> skillset) {
        this.skillset = skillset;
    }`
```

**SkillSet.Java**

`

```
package aurozen.assign.aurozenassign.entity;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import lombok.ToString;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
public class Skillset {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int skillid;

    private String skillname;

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "empId", nullable = false,updatable = false, insertable = true)
    private Employee employee;

    public int getSkillid() {
        return skillid;
    }

    public void setSkillid(int skillid) {
        this.skillid = skillid;
    }

    public String getSkillname() {
        return skillname;
    }

    public void setSkillname(String skillname) {
        this.skillname = skillname;
    }

    public Employee getEmployee() {
        return employee;
    }

    public void setEmployee(Employee employee) {
        this.employee = employee;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Skillset{" +
                "skillid='" + skillid + '\'' +
                ", skillname='" + skillname + '\'' +
                ", employee=" + employee +
                '}';
    }
}
```

`

EmployeeRepositry.java

```
package aurozen.assign.aurozenassign.repositry;


import aurozen.assign.aurozenassign.entity.Employee;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import java.util.Optional;

@Repository
public interface EmployeeRepositry extends JpaRepository<Employee, Integer> {

    Optional<Employee> findByEmpcontact(String s);
}
```

SkillSetRepositry.java

```
package aurozen.assign.aurozenassign.repositry;


import aurozen.assign.aurozenassign.entity.Skillset;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

public interface SkillsetRepositry extends JpaRepository<Skillset, Integer> {
}
```

**Controller**

```
@PostMapping(value = "/signup",produces = {"application/json"})
    public Employee addEmployee(@RequestBody Employee employee) {
        empRepo.save(employee);
        return employee;
    }
```

**Json Data**

```
{
        "empname": "sandep",
        "empcontact": "9650114890",
        "empemail": "aidaih",
        "empphoto": "paidpaid",
        "skillset": [
            {
                "skillname": "jop"
            }
        ]
    }
```

I have attached Db Screenshot 
[Database Screenshot with empid as foreign key in skillset table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4qy4x.png)

foreign key(empid) in the skillset table always populating to null when ever I try to post the data through postman.other fields getting populating without any problem in both the table

Comment: Please describe your problem in text. Also include relevant code and error messages as text. Images are fine to clarify things that can't easily  be expressed in text.

Comment: Sorry, but no. I'm not going to click through a bunch images in order to guess what you are doing and what your problem is.

Comment: sorry ,I have updated it .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relationship between `Skillset` and `Employee` is owned by `Skillset`. This means JPA will persist the state the `Skillset` objects have.

But via `@RequestBody` you are creating an `Employee` instance.
While that references a `Skillset` instances, that instance does not reference the `Employee`. 
Therefor no relationship gets persisted.

To fix this add code to `setSkillset` to set the `employee` property of it.
Something like this should do:

```
public void setSkillset(List<Skillset> skillset) {
    this.skillset = skillset;
    skillset.foreach(s -> s.setEmployee(this));
}
```